# Eclipse + m2e + junit5 - already possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, m2e, junit5, java-11

Tried to get **Eclipse** 2018-09 + Patch with **Java 11** support, **m2e**, and **junit5** working together.

As recommended in *[junit5-modular-world](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-modular-world)* example I introduced a second *module-info.java* under *test/java*.

The reaction of Eclipse was astonishing to me:

I could not save that file after changing it.
It was saved only by closing Eclipse at all.
However, re-opening, bewildered Eclipse. It cannot show any details of the project hosting multiple *module-info.java*, just the project name.

Probably Eclipse identifies one project with one Java module, while *mvn test* compiles and executes obviously a different module than the one created by *mvn install*.

Experienced a lot of options I can think of. Currently I had to give up and fall back to junit 4.12.

Do you know of a better solution?

Comment: not very friendly with eclipse though, yet could you elaborate ... *while mvn test compiles and executes obviously a different module than the one created by mvn install.* ?

Comment: I am not an Eclipse expert. The effect I see in Eclipse 2018-09 about multiple "module-info.java" may not show problems in Eclipse rather than in my understanding how to use it. How should I use it? If my understanding that there are two top-modules (from Java point of view) - the product and its test - in one Eclipse project, how shall I handle the product and the test in that one Eclipse project?

Answer (score 1):

A secondary `module-info.java` in the test source folder is not supported by Eclipse at this time (but its behaviour if you try to do that should probably be improved).

For now, you probably won't need it at all:

Maven puts dependencies that are mentioned in the module-info.java on the module path, all others (e.g. test-only dependencies like junit) on the class path, so they become part of the unnamed module. When tests are compiled, command line options are added, so the test code that is treated as part of the module in the main source folder still can read the unnamed module (by adding `--add-reads modulename=ALL-UNNAMED`), so junit is visible to the test code.

Eclipse Photon and later also supports this behaviour.

Some background regarding the secondary test `module-info.java`: maven-compiler-plugin supports this since version 3.8 (see https://www.mail-archive.com/announce@maven.apache.org/msg00866.html, implemented in issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-341), but I'm not aware that a matching maven-surefire-plugin has been released, so I think you currently wouldn't be able to run these kinds of tests with maven.

Implementing support for a secondary test `module-info.java` in Eclipse may be possible, as long as it is a strict superset of of the primary `module-info.java` in the main source folder, or maybe as long as they specify the same module and their contents would get  merged as in the "pro" build tool https://github.com/forax/pro. But nobody has worked on that yet.

What will probably be never supported in Eclipse, is to have a secondary test `module-info.java` that specifies a different module as Eclipse has the assumption that one java project belongs to only one module. But that shouldn't matter, as these tests can only use public and exported code of the main sources, so they can simply be put into their own maven module.

Comment: That were the hints I needed: I took the [junit5-jupiter-starter-maven](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven) example and added a _module-info.java_ and a required module.
I had to add the required module to the Modulepath (_Configure Build Path..._) and the _junit-jupiter-api_ and _junit-jupiter-params_ to the _Classpath_ (and not to the _Modulepath_).

Unfortunately I had to add _opens "my module"_ to _module-info.java_ in order to give junit-jupiter acces to internals.

After that, _Run As / Maven test_ tested the module as expected.

Comment: Good to hear. BTW:  If you use maven and the m2e plugin and import the project as maven project, m2e should automatically put the dependencies on Eclipse's modulepath/classpath as needed by the module-info.java. Also, when you do "Run As JUnit Test" in Eclipse, it should add the "--add-opens" for junit automatically. I think maven-surefire-plugin does that, too, but maybe I tested only with JUnit4 and maybe I even remember this incorrectly

Comment: Actually now I remember: When I tested, maven-surefire-plugin ran the tests completely on the classpath, so --add-opens was not needed then (but no module system functionality was available during testing either)

Comment: I was not able to somehow do the Modulepath or Classpath automatically. Also I found no way to omit the *"opens 'module';"* statement. I pushed my experience to [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/ngong1/junit5-jupiter-starter-m2e-java11-eclipse) and would appreciate to find out what to do better.
More serious to me was that I lost the code completion and code recommendation feature of JDT editor in Eclipse.

Comment: I've imported your project using m2e. Then I've removed the manually added entries for the jars from the classpath/modulepath (The Maven Dependencies container is shown on the classpath, but its contents are distributed between classpath modulepath as necessary). Now the project compiled successfully and I was able to run CalculatorTests as Junit Tests as expected.

Comment: I was also able to run the test using `mvn clean test`

Comment: Actually you shouldn't have to configure compliance etc. That should be done automatically by m2e. Just in case you've e.g. added the JDK11 to the eclipse JREs after importing the project, you may have to right-click on the project and choose `Maven > Update Project...`

Comment: Thank you for investigating. That is true, Till, that m2e behaves as mvn from the commandline. And neither is dependent on the manual entries I added to the Module- and Classpath found in the properties of the Eclipse project. However, if I omit these references, I see lots of failures in JDT editor, not able to write a class or test class. Did you deleted "opens ..." from module-info.java? I understood, this could be added by m2e and/or mvn at runtime. And (3rd) did you're code recommendations work?

Comment: Yes, when I run the test, the command line contains "--add-opens eu.ngong.m2e11j5/eu.ngong.m2e11j5=ALL-UNNAMED " (You can see the command line by right-clicking in the debug view on the entry of the terminated process with the exit values and choosing "Properties")

Comment: ok - super. Something is different at my side: `/opt/jdk-11/bin/java -Dmaven.home=EMBEDDED -Dclassworlds.conf=/home/rsc/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.launching/launches/m2conf5081448225638622130.tmp -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/rsc/eclipse-workspace/junit5-jupiter-starter-m2e-java11-eclipse -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/eclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.9.1.20180912-1600/jars/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -B test`

Comment: You are basically launching "mvn test" from within eclipse. I was launching the JUnit-Tests using Eclipse's JUnit Launch Configuration (by right-clicking on the project, source folder, package, class or method and choosing "Run As > JUnit Test").

Comment: Ok, thank you Till - I guess I am trough, updated gitlab accordingly. Would appreciate your comment if you find anything to comment on in README.md.